# Making to make a web crawler and a link tree purely in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web, cross-domain, web-crawler

In one of my assignments I have to make a web crawler, purely in JavaScript. That means, the input will be an URL and output will be a tree of all the links starting from that page.
I used the plugin https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/ which uses YQL and it worked for fetching all the links on the site. (Like I did for the Google's Homepage , http://deepakpathak.in/langoor/linkfinder.html). However I am having trouble making a tree structure out of it. 
Is there any other simpler way to make a tree of links of a given website, and that in Javascript?

Comment: Is the purpose to make a sitemap or something?

Comment: @Spoike Not exactly a web spider but a Site navigator, for an editor, which has a tree navigation on sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not mentioning what kind of tree you want to do, should the output be a tree list component on a website of some sort or do you want to put it in a database?

However you can use plain old javascript objects and arrays to create your [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) (look up any notes on the tree data structure to see how they work there are many ways to represent them). To get you started a basic tree can look like this (with a `createNode` function):

```
var createNode = function(content) {
    return {
        'nodes': [], // children are put here
        'content': content // puts the content here
    };
};

var treeroot = createNode();
    // create the root node of the tree
    // content is undefined

treeroot.nodes.push(createNode(myTreeNode)); 
    // accesses the nodes array and pushes a new node into the root node
    // content in that node will be whatever "myTreeNode" is
```

You do have to write traversal algorithms yourself as javascript doesn't have any functions to handle trees. Alternatively create your tree using the DOM itself (as it is a tree data structure).